Better proof for triangle inequality for $n$ vectors
As a bit of context: I'm trying to prove that that $|x_1| + ... + |x_n| \geq \sqrt{x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2}$.
In order to do so I've thought about using the triangle inequality: $||\mathbf{u}|| + ||\mathbf{v}||\geq ||\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}|| $. Since $||\mathbf{u}||$ is equivalent to the absolute value $|{u}|$ if $\mathbf{u}$ is a scalar.
However the initial statement is about $n$ different elements of the sum and the triangle inequality is for two vectors. In order to prove that the triangle inequality is valid for more than 2 vectors
I've done the following:
Let 3 vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{y},\mathbf{v}$:
$||\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{v}||$ if we rename $\mathbf{y+v} = \mathbf{k}$, then:
$||\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{k}|| \leq ||\mathbf{u}|| + ||\mathbf{k}|| = ||\mathbf{u}|| + ||\mathbf{y+v}|| \leq ||\mathbf{u}|| + ||\mathbf{y}|| + ||\mathbf{v}||$.
While this proof is correct, I feel it is a bit sloppy. For $n$ vectors  I would have to repeat the rename step $n$ times until all the vectors are alone in the form of $||\mathbf{x_i}||$.
Is there a better way to do so rather than recursively applying this idea?
Thanks!

Why do you feel it is sloppy?

Because of what i mention that if i wanted to prove it for $n$ vectors, rather than just 3, the proof would be really long and quite repetitive. It would be repeating the renaming step $n$ times.

Use induction on $n$.

Not really used to doing proofs, so im not really familiar with those involving induction. Will check out. Thanks!

Actually vectors and triangular inequalities are not necessarily needed to prove this. To show $|x_1| + ... + |x_n| \geq \sqrt{x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2}$ it suffices to show
$$
\left(|x_1| + ... + |x_n|\right)^2 \geq x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2
$$
Since both sides are non-negative. However, this holds since
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|x_ix_j|
$$
And each absolute value is non-negative. $\blacksquare$
